# How to use named back reference to mach multiple occurrences in Perl's regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to strip double quotes around numbers in all arrays from a JSON output. e.g.

```
["123","345","5567" ...]
```

should become:

```
[123, 345, 5567 ...]
```

I can locate the array part using something like:

```
/\[("(?<name>\d+)"[,]*)*\]/
```

However, I didn't succeed to replace `(?<name>\d+)` with `$+{name}` because there are multiple occurrences of `$+{name}`... Can anybody shed me any light?

Comment: Why are you not using the JSON module to handle your JSON data?

Comment: Sometime when the number is very large, I end up having quotes around numbers. e.g.: [1334,23222,"5435433555555555555554353"]. I try to use bignum but it still couldn't resolve the issue in a general way.

Comment: For some reason, `use bignum` causes the below JSON code to crash. That is surprising.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the data into a Perl data structure with the `JSON` module, convert the strings to numbers, then output the json again:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $string = qq(["123","345","5567"]);
my $data   = from_json($string);

print Dumper to_json($data);   # datastructure before conversion
$_ += 0 for @$data;
print Dumper to_json($data);   # after
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = '["123","345","5567"]';
$VAR1 = '[123,345,5567]';
```

Of course, this will only work for strings that are numbers, so you will need to validate your data if you have non-numbers in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, TLP. This is exactly what I am doing now. and I also used: "use bignum" to handle large numbers. But unfortunately, some numbers are still with quotes... For sanity concerns I just want to add a regular expression filter to make sure no quotes were seen.

Comment: Perhaps there is a reason those numbers are quoted, to avoid big number concerns.